# Toggle Key in Java

Tags: java, key, toggle

Basically I'm trying to toggle boolean every time F1 key is pressed.
In my main class I've got update method that is called 60 times a second and I coded something like this:

Main.class:

```
private Keyboard key = new Keyboard; // keyboard object
boolean debug; // boolean to control visibility of debug screen
private boolean toggle; // used to toggle boolean

private void update() { // update is called 60/s
    if (key.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.f1) && !toggle) {
        debug = !debug;
        toggle = true;
    } else if (!key.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.f1)) toggle = false;
}
```

Keyboard.class:

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

private boolean[] keys = new boolean[65536];

public static final int f1 = KeyEvent.VK_F1; // key code of f1 key

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public boolean isKeyPressed(int key) {
    return keys[key];
}
```

And this way it works perfect, but if I create similar method in Keyboard.class it does not work:

update method in main class:

```
private void update() {
    key.toggle(Keyboard.f1, debug); // toggle boolean debug if f1 key pressed, but.. NOT WORKING!! WHYYY!!?
}
```

Keyboard.class:

```
private boolean toggle;

public void toggle(int key, boolean b) {
    if (isKeyPressed(key) && !toggle) {
        b = !b;
        toggle = true;
    } else if (!isKeyPressed(key)) toggle = false;
}
```

And my question is:
*Why is the second way not working and how can I fix it to work?*
Thank you!

Comment: You're not updating the `keys` array, so, in theory, the `F1` key is always pressed.  Using `b = !b` is useless, as parameter will only be changed within the context of the method, the change will not be reflected to caller

Answer (score 1):

Thank you MadProgrammer, you're right! ;D

Main.class:

```
private void update() {
    debug = key.toggle(Keyboard.f1, debug); 
}
```

Keyboard.class:

```
private boolean toggle;

public boolean toggle(int key, boolean b) {
    if (isKeyPressed(key) && !toggle) {
        b = !b;
        toggle = true;
    } else if (!isKeyPressed(key) && toggle) {
        toggle = false;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Now it returns the value I wanted, thanks man, I completely forgot about that.
Is there any better/easier way to do that?